# How can I send and receive faxes using Emacs?

Tags: untagged

How can I send and receive faxes using Emacs?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 4):

In the '90s there was some chatter about building a fax mode around HylaFAX, and I recall at least one third party package that might have used its own fax software. Maybe it was called `sendfax`? I won't link them here because 25 year old pet projects aren't going to provide much help, but you can google them if you want.

Today I'd recommend you combine one of the many Emacs email clients (`gnus`,`mu4e`, `vm`, `rmail`, `notmuch`, etc) and an e-fax/faxmail service. Ie: you send an email to your e-fax provider and it forwards it on as a fax for you.

Comment: Thank you for this. That's a great set of ideas, and I happen to spot the email-to-fax services. This will work just fine, as I use Mu4e now anyway. I'm only looking at this, on a 'need to do' basis.